# Advanced Data Structures in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm fairly new to C++ and was wondering if anyone could help me identify some good advanced data structures to use in my university project. I've tried contacting my lecturer for help but they are unresponsive.

I'm creating a self solving wordsearch and have already done a 'simple' version where I used a 2D array and a string vector but I also need to create an advanced version with advanced data structures.

Anyway here is the following descriptions of what the specification says for both:

Wordsearch Grid - A more advanced data structure recognises that any letter cell in the grid can form part of eight sequences (horizontal, vertical, and two diagonals, each of which may be read in either direction). Therefore, a data structure can be created based on individual ‘letter cell’ objects that are linked into sequences that can be uniformly checked by one standard comparison method. This comparison method would be invoked for each direction from each cell of the puzzle grid in turn, to compare the letter sequences from that point against the dictionary content. Regular row-by row traversal of this structure will remain possible (e.g., for data loading) by following the forward pointing horizontal links for each row, and the downward vertical links from the first cell in each row, starting from the top left corner. The advanced puzzle’s size is defined in the text data file, and is N x N where N is an integer value >= 9.

Word Dictionary - A more advanced data structure recognises that many longer words may begin with the same letter sequence as (or the entirety of) some shorter word(s). For example, the dictionary may contain the words PROJECT and PROJECTOR, therefore PROJECTOR only requires two more letters matching than the word PROJECT. If the word matching process has to start each dictionary word string from the beginning, then such common sequences will be matched several times until the match is found or the search completely fails.

If anyone could help me by letting me know which data structures would be ideal for these it would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: i beleive a trie is useful for the second case

Comment: @pm100 thank you I searched it up and it definitely seems to fit the bill, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simpler is better than fancy, especially if you actually want to implement this in C++.

So, for the grid, I would actually consider just using a plain one-dimensional array of entries. All you want to do is have different ways of iterating over it. Consider this example grid which can live in a `std::array<char,N*N> data`:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

One way to search in it is horizontally, so:

```
Iterator begin_horz(std::size_t const row) const {
  return Iterator{begin(data) + row*N, 1};
}
Iterator end_horz(std::size_t const row) const {
  return Iterator{begin(data) + row*N + N, 1};
}
```

similarly, if you want to iterate vertically:

```
Iterator begin_vert(std::size_t const col) const {
  return Iterator{begin(data) + col, N};
}
Iterator end_vert(std::size_t const col) const {
  return Iterator{begin(data) + col + N*N-N, N};
}
```

and further on for both diagonals. The reverse can be done by defining a reverse operation for Iterator.

That `Iterator` type, will then just increment the underlying `std::array::iterator` by the passed value with each `Iterator::operator++`

This has the advantage, that the data is packed as tightly as possible, decreasing the chances of cache misses.

Comment: "... that the date is packed ..."  Did you mean "data"?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Yes, I did. I mistyped. Thanks.